# CakePHP 2.1.3 Shell, how to create email link

Tags: php, shell, email, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

How to create email link from CakePHP Shell?
If I did the normal way, e.g:

```
<?php echo 
$this->Html->link($task['Project']['subject'], array('full_base' => true,
  'admin' => false,
  'controller' => 'projects',
  'action' => 'view',
  $task['Project']['id']                                  
  )
);
?>
```

it will resulting in `localhost/projects/view/12` instead of `flat.com/projects/view/12`

I did try overwrite in bootstap smtg like:

```
define('FULL_BASE_URL', 'http://flat.com');
```

It will work but will cause session problem, which I'm not sure why. e.g: when I logout on flat.com, if I go to www.flat.com, it will still show login. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: @AD7six how do I do the www redirect? what should I put in routes.php? and how to define the full base url on CLI only? please advice. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Avoid the problem

> It will work but will cause session problem, [...] when I logout on flat.com, if I go to www.flat.com

Having an application which responds to multiple hostnames can be problematic, and is best avoided. The easiest solution to *that* problem, is to ensure that there is only one domain in use for the application

For example [using apache](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/.htaccess#L217-L242) add the following to the webroot .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Or [using nginx](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/sites-available/example.com#L1-L14) add a server block like so:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  # listen on the www host
  server_name www.example.com;

  # and redirect to the non-www host
  return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

### Or just define the constant on the cli

Alternatively, conditionally define the constant in your bootstrap file:

```
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
    define('FULL_BASE_URL', 'http://example.com');
}
```

Comment: So, I tried the conditionally define constant, it does not work. If I put this in ReminderShell.php if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
    define('FULL_BASE_URL', 'http://flat.dev');
}, it will say constant FULL_BASE_URL already defined. and if I use Configure::write, nothing happen. it still go to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this at **Config/core.php**:

```
Configure::write('App.fullBaseURL', 'http://domain.ext/');
```